# How to get only selected cells value from filtered cells from excel

Tags: c#, import-from-excel

I have a simple excel sheet:

[image]

Now, I filter it such that cell value > 1. Now my data looks like:

[image]

Now, I select the data that I require:

[image]

Note that I have selected all the Mobile Numbers.

Now in my code, I am trying to retrieve all the selected data as follows:

```
Range selection = (Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
```

But, it gives me the cells from starting to ending. I think excel selects the non-visible rows also. Because row no 4 that contains 0 is also retrieved. Look at the image below:

[image]

So, now I created another Range and tried to add all the values of cells that are visible as follows:

```
Range onlyFilteredSelection = selection.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
```

Now, I can see that c# shows me only the two rows. Why is it not displaying the last row, which is after the non-filtered row. Take a look at the values here:

[image]

**Update:**

After posting this question, I got a thought in my mind that I might be getting multiple ranges instead of 1 and so, I started exploring. And look what I have found. I found that I was exactly right. I get multiple ranges.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
Range selection = (Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;

List<Range> onlyFilteredSelection = new List<Range>();

foreach (Range range in selection.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible))
{
    onlyFilteredSelection.Add(range);
}
```

Now, I get 4 items in `selection` variable. And in `onlyFilteredSelection` has got 3 items.

**Now, I am in another trouble:**

Previously, I was getting a Range, so I converted it to a Comma-Separated String very much easily using the below mentioned code:

```
string[] AllRecepientMobileNumberValues = ((Array)(selection.Cells.Value2)).OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
string RecepientMobileNumberValue = AllRecepientMobileNumberValues.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x);
```

But now, I get a List. So, now my big question is how to Convert a List to Comma-Separated string?????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more `Select` to get the values out of a list.

```
string[] AllRecepientMobileNumberValues = onlyFilteredSelection.Select(x => x.Cells.Value2).OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
string RecepientMobileNumberValue = AllRecepientMobileNumberValues.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x);
```

Comment: That's it. It works just fine. I was very much tensed that I even didn't realized the select clause. Thanks for answering it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried around a bit and had problems too. But I think I may have found a **possible workaround** for your situation. First some things I found out.

- I was able to reproduce your behaviour
- the selection of all visible cells fails, because a filter (seems?) not to hide the rows, but it set the row height to 0!
- I could not find any other useful method/property when looking around on the [Application Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application_members.aspx) or the [Range Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members.aspx).

I created a **macro** to **record** what **VBA** code would be generated on a copy action of your selection´too. Strange thing is that there is nothing special in the code as you can see.

**vba macro code**

```
Range("A3:A5").Select   ' correct as three lines are selected,
                        ' but only two of them have a rowHeight > 0
Selection.Copy
Range("F8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste   ' and here is the magic?? why does vba only paste 2 cells??
```

So I decided to come up with a workaround. Why not simulation what VBA seemingly does too. Only handle those cells whose `rowHeight > 0`.

**exampleCode.cs**

```
private static void readFilteredCells()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    Workbook xlBook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
    Worksheet wrkSheet = xlBook.Worksheets[1];

    Range selection = xlApp.Selection;

    for (int rowIndex = selection.Row; rowIndex < selection.Row + selection.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        if (wrkSheet.Rows[rowIndex].EntireRow.Height!=0)
        {
            // do something special
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my answer is of any use for you. If you need any further assistance please let me know.

Comment: Yes, your answer is of-course of use, but I may say that your assumptions were wrong. To see that please check the update part of the question. And if you can then please try to answer another question in Update section of question. And thanks for your efforts........

Comment: Thx for sharing your solution! Glad you could solve your problem.